# selenium.mouseOver does not open the menu

Tags: selenium

I have an application where I need to do mouseOver over a particular menu. The issue is that selenium.mouseOver is not able to open the respective menu, it just seems to highlight that div [it appears to be in pressed down state]. 
This div has 'onmouseover' attribute available which calls a javascript to expand this menu.
Seems that when using selenium.mouseover this javascript is not getting called. It works fine when executed manually.
I am using firefox 3.6 and it is a Richface application.

I also tried with mouseDown and click but it does not work. Is there any solution or workaround available for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues (such as [these for jquery](http://articles.rootsmith.ca/jquery/mouseover-events-in-selenium-and-jquery-hover)) with regards to Selenium and `mouseover` events.  You might try, if your browser supports it, the `mouseenter` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
>   Actions hoverOverRegistrar = builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("blah blah"))); 
>   hoverOverRegistrar.perform();